# Disk boot failure in Windows 7 64-bit after installing the latest NVIDIA drivers

Tags: windows-7, boot, mbr

I successfully installed the newest NVIDIA drivers (275.33) in Windows 7 64-bit and rebooted afterwards just in case. After the reboot, I got an error about missing MBR. I disconnected the slave disk so that Windows doesn't get confused and got this message:

> DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER

It seems that Windows doesn't recognize the main disk anymore. I booted from Windows install disk but the main disk doesn't get listed as possible Windows locations to repair, and I can't get to it from the recovery prompt.

The BIOS does recognize it, and I'm able to see it if I run `diskpart` - however "detail disk" in diskpart says that there are no volumes on the disk. I also tried `bootrec /FixMbr` without effect, and `bootrec /FixBoot` which gives the error message:

> Element not found.

What else can I do? Why would diskpart say there are no volumes on the disk?

Comment: Try some of the other Bootrec commands...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: Its possible the hard drive has failed, download the hard drive manufacturers utility to test the hard drive.

Comment: Moab, I did everything the Microsoft support article suggested. Didn't help. Disk and data is fine - see my answer below how I finally resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, while I haven't solved my problem (see my [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/302603/problem-recreating-bcd-on-windows-7-64bit-the-requested-system-device-cannot-be)), I did get a bit farther. I used TestDisk from [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) to recover partitions by following (more or less) [this step-by-step tutoral](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). Afterwards, Windows is at least attempting to boot, and when I boot with Windows installation I'm able to access my data via command prompt, as well as from Linux/Windows XP if I boot from Hiren's Boot CD.

Comment: You should have edited your original post here to continue the discussion or add new information, no need to make another Question or post new information as an Answer.

Comment: Since I have completely different issue now, it seemed to me that it's better to simply ask another question, with proper subject, keywords etc.