# Cannot fix Windows 8's BCD, "fatal device hardware error"

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot

Yesterday I turned on my laptop and it got stuck in an infinite Boot/bluescreen/automated repair/black screen loop. I booted into linux from a flash drive and performed memtest86 (everything ok there) and HDD SMART tests (100% ok). I then booted to Windows Recovery using Windows 8's bootable installation flash drive and tried to change the BCD records to make the system stop on the Bluescreen so I can jot down the error number, so I typed in

> "bcdedit /set  onetimeadvancedoptions on"

in the recovery console and I got a message saying

> "the boot configuration data store could not be opened. The system
> cannot find the file specified"

I've found a question on SU of someone with a similar problem ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/302603/problem-recreating-bcd-on-windows-7-64bit-the-requested-system-device-cannot-b)) that recommended following the tips in [this article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Windows+Bootloader+from+the+DVD). But as soon as I got to

> "attrib -h -s C:\boot\BCD"

I got

> Path not found - C:\boot

So I tried

> cd C:/boot

And I got an uneasing message saying

> The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error

I've tried CHKDSK with

> chkdsk C: /F

which returned

> A disk read error occuredc0000483
>
> Insufficient disk space to fix the Usn Journal $J data stream.
>
> Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50

I find it hard to believe that my SSD is heavily damaged, as under Linux I can read and manage files on it just fine.
Where should I go from now on?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed my problem . Apparently when Windows 8's chkdsk encounteres damaged USN Journal, it stops and doesn't fix it. I ran chkdsk from a XP installation disk and it fixed the issue in no time.