# Windows 8.1 Boot Issues - Possibly Graphics Driver?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, windows-8.1, safe-mode, bcdedit

Yesterday I was notified my desktop was going to restart in 15 minutes. So I quickly finished what I was doing and I clicked "Restart and Update." I let it shut down and restart like normal but when it rebooted it went through the BIOS, then loaded the Windows 8 logo & the loading spinner. After this the screen goes black but if I move my mouse it will appear with the blue loading spinner, and if I leave it for a while the mouse disappears and goes back to the center of the screen if I move it again.

I have spent several hours researching this on Google and from what I found it is an issue with the Graphics Drivers, which makes sense because the monitors are on as if they are receiving input and I can see my mouse.

I attempted to boot into safe mode but it was being a pain. This is what I attempted so far:

- I put in the install disk and tried to do an `Automatic Repair`
- Then I tried to boot into safe mode but I can't get into safe mode
- I put in the install disk and opened the command prompt to try and enable safe mode by using this command: `BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY LEGACY`but I am getting an error: `the boot configuration data store could not be opened. the requested system device cannot be found`

I custom built my desktop last summer and everything was fine. Windows 8 is installed on an SSD and I have a HDD. I have a NVIDIA Graphic Card.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: First of all, unplug all devices except monitor, keyboard and mouse (if you have USB mouse or keyboard, unplug them too), and restart. Does it repeat?

Comment: Yes, I unplugged everything (except my two monitors). I also unplugged the power adapter and held the power button for 30 seconds, then plugged it back in, but still the same 'black screen'

Comment: What happened when you started in safe-mode? Where it stucks?

Comment: I couldn't get into Safe Mode. That is part of the issue.

Comment: Here is what I attempted:Restart Windows 8 computer and insert Windows 8 bootable media into optical media drive (CD/DVD Drive).
On the displayed Windows Setup box, click Next.
On the next page, click Repair your computer.
On Choose an option screen, click Troubleshoot.
On Troubleshoot screen, click Advanced options.
On Advanced options screen, click Command Prompt.
On the opened Command Prompt window type C: and hit Enter.
On C: prompt, type BCDEDIT /SET {DEFAULT} BOOTMENUPOLICY LEGACY command, and press Enter. But I am getting the error above in my questions.

Comment: Can this help with the safe boot error: http://superuser.com/questions/302603/problem-recreating-bcd-on-windows-7-64bit-the-requested-system-device-cannot-b

Comment: I looked at that and various other solutions. I was getting various errors with everything I tried and I ended up just reinstalling Windows

Comment: What was the update about?

Answer (score 0):

This may look like a weird solution, but [this thread](http://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/23078-how-enter-safe-mode-when-system-totally-frozen.html) saved my day after wasting 2 hours on this. I had a very similar issue as yours (faulty AMD graphic card driver causing black screen with blinking cursor, no way to enter Windows, and impossible to boot into safe mode from any recovery media):

1. Reboot your computer. During the reboot phase, when the Windows logo appears, **immediately press the power button until the computer shuts down**. Start the computer and do this sequence **at least 3 times**.
2. Then, start your computer without touching anything. The 3 previous forcibly failed boots will have been detected by Windows and it will automatically start in recovery mode, without the need for any recovery media! And most importantly, the "Start-Up Settings" option will be available to choose from. There, it will finally be possible to select to reboot in safe mode with all the usual alternatives (with or without networking support, etc.).

This is not clean at all but I found zero other way to get into safe mode. I hope it helps! And if a Windows developer falls on this question, that they will consider making this process a bit more user friendly.