# Cannot import bcd.temp when trying to rebuild corrupt BCD on Windows 2012 server 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2012, bcd, bcdedit

I have a Windows 2012 server which died on me a week ago. There is a full description of what's gone wrong [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/866680/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked-on-windows-server-2012).

It seemed I'd finally found a solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/302603/problem-recreating-bcd-on-windows-7-64bit-the-requested-system-device-cannot-b). I have moved to USB2.0 to eliminate that possibility and was going through the solution posted by the OP on that superuser question. However, as noted in the comments on his solution, it's not possible to use the `/import` and `/store` parameters together. Strangely, someone in the comments suggested they have edited the question to fix this, but as noted by others, it doesn't seem they have.

Same as the OP on the question above, I have been trying to use [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/#Attempt_Three_Nuclear_Holocaust) tutorial, but when I try to run the command `bcdedit.exe /import c:\boot\bcd.temp` I get a message that the decide cannot be found. As I am new to superuser I can't comment on the original post.

Does anyone know the answer here? The commentor Nathan Brown says "The solution is to not create a temporary store and import but just create and work on the actual store using the /store flag for all commands." But it's not clear what this means or involves.

Comment: When you run `bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:`, did you replace `C:` with `D:`?

Comment: You may also try `bcdboot D:\Windows /s C:`. You may want to delete the entire `C:\boot` before that as well.

Comment: Either case, `D:` is used because it is the "main" partition, while `C:` is the System Reserved partition, according to diskpart. You may want to make sure this is the case whenever you run any commands and swap the drive letters to use otherwise. Also make sure the System Reserved partition is the active partition.

Comment: I had tried `bcdboot D:\Windows /s C:`. And I haven't yet got to `bcdedit.exe /set {bootmgr} device partition=C:`, because like the user on the other thread, I am getting a failure when I run `bcdedit.exe /import c:\boot\bcd.temp`.

Comment: Oh I missed that the step is a later one. So how does bcdboot go? Has it completed successfully? And what's the result of booting afterwards?

Comment: It completes. When I boot, the Windows logo comes up, but then hangs with a blank screen after a couple of seconds of that.

Comment: Because bcdboot is all you need to reinstall the Windows Boot Manager and a working BCD system store comes with it. As long as the System Reseverd partition is the active partition so that the bootmgr (hence the working BCD) on it is loaded, it should boot fine. If it doesn't, the problem probably lies on the main installation.

Comment: The partition that's marked as active is the one that Diskpart calls C: (though C was actually the same of the one with Windows installed when it was running, which Diskpart calls D). It's a 350MB partition which, as I understand it, is the System Reserved.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds to me like some registry conflict problem on the mounted devices I experienced. I couldn't recall the details though coz I only experienced it once after some cloning or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to resolve this. A full description is currently on Serverfault, [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/866680/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked-on-windows-server-2012) In short, completely rebuilding the BCD eventually worked, but took several attempts as well as waiting approximately four hours for the server to boot afterwards.

Comment: The link is broken. Also, please quote the answer.

Comment: Edited accordingly.