# Replace Windows bootmgr file

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bcd, bootmgr

I had a problem with booting windows 10 because I've changed the `bootmgr` path using : `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} newpath`

after rebooting it said that the boot sector is corrupted.
Using Linux I can enter to the windows EFI partition and see the `bootmgr` file, but unfortunately the file is in binary (I've used a hex editor to open it).

Is it possible to replace it with another bootmgr file ?

if so from where to download it
else
is it possible to change the path using a hex editor ?

> P.S : I've already used the windows rescue CD to run command and fix
>   it from there but it doesn't work

Comment: You didn’t change the `bootmgr` binary. You changed the _B_oot _C_onfiguration _D_ata. You need Windows (Windows PE/Setup is sufficient) to fix this. Which command, exactly, did you run to fix it?

Comment: first i've used diskpart
>diskprt
>sel disk 0
>list vol
>select volume 2 (which is the EFI partition)
> assign letter = Y
>exit
>cd /d Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
>bootrec /fixboot
>ren BCD BCD.bak
>bcdboot.exe c:\Windows /l en-us /s Y: /f all

Comment: That information belongs in the question. You can also use proper formatting there. // Since you already have Linux on hand, please also provide the output of efibootmgr's list command. (I'm away from my PC now, sorry for the lack of details.)

Comment: @DanielB i've fixed the problem using a Method i've found here -> http://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/ Thanks to this guy  https://superuser.com/a/308590

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed the problem using ["The Nuclear Holocaust"](http://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/)

Thanks to this [Comment](https://superuser.com/a/308590)

Thank you @DanielB for your time and thanks @Domichi for leading me :)