# access denied with bootrec /fixboot

Tags: boot, efi, bcd

I got a new SSD for my windows 10 home desktop computer recently. I used macrium to clone the HDD -> SSD and changed bios to boot from SSD.
But when I tried cleaning the HDD I somehow corrupted something in the windows boot process (no idea how it happened, I never even touched my SSD).

When I start windows I get error code 0xc000000e (A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed), so I have to go into recovery mode.

Most people online fix this by using bootrec, or worst case scenario bootsect.  Nothing works for me.

A lengthy list of things I've tried with notes can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Almenon/1ad4a4d42ef1f8eb007d1289a6fcac0e

Answer (score 5):

FIXED! Thank god!

The problem was that I was booting the recovery usb normally (just selecting the usb).  It is super-duper-EXTRA important that you select boot to the usb UEFI option!  Once I did that stuff started working again. To get my SSD back up and running I did the following:

1. boot to UEFI recovery usb
2. launch cmd
3. bootrec /ScanOs (you should find an instance)
4. bootrec /FixMbr
5. bootrec /FixBoot (if you get error, do bootsect /nt60 SYS and try again)
6. bootrec /RebuildBcd

Thanks to @Jan-Philip Gehrcke for the tip! (see [Problem recreating BCD on Windows 7 64bit - The requested system device cannot be found](https://superuser.com/questions/302603))

Comment: Just wanted to add that _this_ was the only thing that solved my problem where I deleted a boot manager on an old disk but forgot to fix the boot manager on my new one (after a disk clone).