# Windows 10 restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Ever since my previous problem ([access denied with bootrec /fixboot](https://superuser.com/questions/1397733/access-denied-with-bootrec-fixboot/1397767#1397767), fixed) I can't shut down my computer via the software. When I try it acts like it's shutting down but then it just goes to the login screen. Instead I have to hold down the power button to do a hard shut down which is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently googled it and came across this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/

It turns out all I had to do is press the shift key while clicking shutdown. Weird fix but okay.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill ..... I did. You need to press the shift key while clicking shutdown, that's the answer.